# Selected Files Not Appearing in Context's addFilesToContext Function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file

the reason for my question is the following.

I have created the following context to handle the images that are selected from an input type file.This is the context:

```
const ContextValues = () => {
   
  const [fileArray, setFileArray] = useState<File[]>([]);

  const addFileToContext = (file: File) => {
    setFileArray(prevFileArray => [...prevFileArray, file]);
  };

  const addFilesToContext = (filesToAdd: File[]) => {
    console.log("this is what it have to save in the hook: "+JSON.stringify(filesToAdd))
    setFileArray(prevFileArray => [...prevFileArray, ...filesToAdd]);
  };

  const clearFileArray = () => {
    setFileArray([])
  }

  return {
    fileArray, setFileArray, addFileToContext, addFilesToContext, clearFileArray
  }
}

export const FilesContext = createContext({} as ReturnType<typeof ContextValues>);

const FilesContextProvider: FC<React.PropsWithChildren<{}>> = (props) => {
  return (
    <FilesContext.Provider value={ContextValues()}>
      {props.children}
    </FilesContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default FilesContextProvider;
```

This is the handle that I use to manage the images.

```
  const handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const fileList = event.target.files; 
    if (fileList) {
      const fileArray = Array.from(fileList); 
      console.log("Selected files:", fileArray);
      addFilesToContext(fileArray);

    } else {
      console.log("No files selected.");
    }
  };
```

The problem is the following: when I select files, the console.log in the handleFileChange function correctly shows the selected files, as you can see in the following image. However, the selected files do not appear in the console.log of the addFilesToContext function inside the context. I am directly passing the fileArray, so why is this happening?

[image]